# How can I serve an index.jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using express, and writing my views in jade. One of them is an index.jade file, id like to serve this file as you would an .html. How would I do this? I tried `res.sendfile('views/index.jade')` and `res.sendfile('views/index.html')`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To render a page, you need to use

```
res.render('index');
```